# How to stop nested sub-items from shrinking in Wagtail Admin?

Tags: wagtail

I am using Wagtail's [StreamField functionality](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.12.1/topics/streamfield.html) to create my site.

The problem is I have many (more than 5) StructBlocks nested inside each other. The resulting UI is unusable because it looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

Is there any way to modify StructBlocks' admin UI to not shrink when nested?

Answer (score 0):

There are no first-party way to do that at the moment.

There are third party which attempt to solve this to various degrees: [Wagtail Clear StreamField](https://github.com/heymonkeyriot/wagtailclearstream), [WagtailFacelift](https://github.com/springload/wagtailfacelift) and another one which I can't seem to find atm. However those solutions are either still WIP or rather hacky which will make upgrading fastidious further down the line.

Your best bet is probably to inject your own styles with the [`insert_editor_css` hook](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/hooks.html#insert-editor-css) but I would advise to keep it as minimal as possible to make upgrading easier later.

On a side note, the next Wagtail Sprint in late October will focus on StreamField UI (including nested blocks) so hopefully this will soon be an old memory.